# Could not open a connection to your authentication agent. Mac OS

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I have seen many solutions on this. I tried command as suggested
    eval `ssh-agent`

And then added keys

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/internal/2015-01-19
```

both with and without K. But i open new terminal and try it ssh-add -l command. it show same error : Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

How to resolve this. Really new on mac.

Answer (score 1):

You’re supposed to execute the output that you get back from "ssh-agent", like this: eval $(ssh-agent)

Then your environment is set up for ssh-add to connect to the agent.
Hope it solved your doubt :)